# Upload file using link button

Tags: asp.net

I wrote a procedure to upload a file into database using FileUpload control like this.

```
 bytes = new byte[] { };
    filename = Path.GetFileName(FUProfile.PostedFile.FileName);
    contentType = FUProfile.PostedFile.ContentType;
    fileLengthInKB = FUProfile.PostedFile.ContentLength / 102400;

    fileName = FUProfile.PostedFile.FileName;
    fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName);
    fileMimeType = FUProfile.PostedFile.ContentType;

    if (FUProfile.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            if (matchExtension.Contains(fileExtension) && matchMimeType.Contains(fileMimeType))
            {
                if (fileLengthInKB <= 102400)
                {
                    using (Stream fs = FUProfile.PostedFile.InputStream)
                    {
                        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
                        {
                            bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
                            clsProjects.UploadedProfile = bytes;
                            clsProjects.UploadedProfileCT = contentType;
                            clsProjects.UploadedProfileName = filename;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    lblResult.Text = "Please choose profile file less than 1MB";
                }
            }
            else
                {
                    lblResult.Text = "Please choose only pdf profile file.";
                }
            }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblResult.Text = "Upload status: The profile file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

I want to do this by using the LinkButton on some forms. I want to select a file (appearing a diagluebox) by pressing LinkButton and save that file into database. Any idea please??

Answer (score 0):

You want like this

Add `ClickOn Event` to your `LinkButton`.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="ENameLinkBtn" runat="server" 
style="font-weight: 700; font-size: 8pt;" 
OnClick="ENameLinkBtn_Click" />
```

Then in your `click event`:

```
protected void ENameLinkBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ....
   ....
}
```

Comment: Yes, because I dont want to use FileUpload control on some forms due to graphical representations.

Comment: How to open a dialogue box to select a file then convert that selected file into InputStream like FULogo.PostedFile.InputStream ???

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you want to do (skipping common FileUpload component) is potentially dangerous. Native browser fileupload component uses OS components to select file (this is also reason why it looks different on each OS), so there is no way somebody could bypass some unwanted file from you local disk on background (e.g. using javascript) and let you upload it to server. If you want some nicer upload component, try to use some [Ajax file uploader](http://blog.insicdesigns.com/2010/02/10-best-ajax-file-uploader-for-your-web-application/).